# Is there a way to upload folders into an Azure TFVC Repo? I only see an option to upload files

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

My company is finally migrating to Azure DevOps.  We are currently using TFS 2013.   We do not wish to migrate our entire repository, only the tip files. When I tried this a couple of years ago in VSTS, it was easy to upload a folder, but this option does not appear to be available any longer.  We have about 500K files, so uploading each one individually is not an option.

Am I missing something?

If not, and we truly can't upload folders any longer, what are my migration options?  Am I forced to use the migration tool to migrate our entire repository or is there any other option?

When I try to drag a folder into the Azure TFVC repo, I get an error message telling me that folders are not supported.   The only button I see is an Upload Files button.

I expect to be able to upload folders from my C drive into TFVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did figure this out.

You simply have to connect to the remote Azure TFVC Repo through Visual Studio and add the files from there.  I don't believe it can be done from the dev.azure.com website.